# Loading static content in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, static-content

I know this is a duplicate and I tried almost all the SO solutions but I couldn't load the static content. Here is my project structure.

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="/js/ice.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I am literally on it from 2 days..

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the URL you are using to access the JSP page ?

Comment: @javaguy, `localhost:8080/SmartXML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. At first, I used cdn to load the static content(which was working) then later on I downloaded all the js and css in my local system(which did not work). When I cleared the cache of Chrome, its started working again. Strange!!